# bundle install hang while installing private gem via ansible playbook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ansible

I am trying to run `bundle install` on a remote host which uses gem from private repo. The task get hang because it stops to accept host key as I can't manually accept the key on the remote host as am running the ansible playbook locally.

> Playbook task

```
  - name: bundle install
    command: bundle install chdir={{ deploy_directory }}
```

How to test or add the github connection via the key file present on the remote host.

I also tried to explicitly accept the key before bundle install by making a test connection to github via ssh.

```
  - name: test connection to git
    command: ssh -vvv git@github.co key_file=/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa accept_hostkey=yes
```

Now This command is also getting hang.

Comment: Is this for a `git:` type gem reference? It's worth noting that GitHub private repos do work as suitable installation sources and I've never had a problem with those.

Comment: @tadman yes I have `git:` type gem reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per `@Ankit_Kukarni` comment, I tried adding `github.com` to `known_hosts` file and finally it worked.

> Adding following piece of code to the playbook

```
  - name: ensure github.com is a known host
    sudo: yes
    lineinfile:
      dest: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts
      create: yes
      state: present
      line: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com') }}"
      regexp: "^github\\.com"
```

A detail explanation can be found [here](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2015/11/avoid-host-key-checking-while-cloning.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can put `export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False` in your ansible play environment . Add this to your play to avoid host key checking .

```
environment:
    ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING:  False
```

Another way could be tried on is to pass the underlying strict key checking parameters to your ssh connection . Parameters are - `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` and `UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` . You can check on the [ansible inventory ssh connection](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html)  and use `ansible_ssh_common_args` or `ansible_ssh_extra_args`

Comment: I tried doing this but somehow its not working. The reason I noticed in the verbose output while the command bundle install is in running state is that the host key verification is getting ignored only for connecting to remote server but not when connecting to the github for installing gem with ssh url

Comment: Try doing this `ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> <your home directory>/.ssh/known_hosts` . This command basically adds github keys to your known hosts file . Once you do this it should no more ask you again until the fingerprint is changing